# Limit pages printed with pdfpages in draft mode

Tags: pdfpages, draft

I use pdfpages alot, and it's a godsend.  One thing I would like it to do, though, is an option to print a limited number of pages, say the first 2, in draft mode so I can make sure I have the correct documents being included.

My application is a document appendix to a legal brief that runs nearly 500 pages, with two or three dozen documents.  I don't want to print the thing in full, but I would like to be able to check that I have the right document attached to each exhibit by printing only the first two or three pages.

Is there any way to accomplish this, or does this fall under the heading "Feature Request".

Comment: `\if@draft \includepdfpdf[pages=1-2]{abc.pdf}\else\includepdf{abc.pdf}\fi` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle one need to disable the draft too, or one see only the file name. something like `\makeatletter
\ifAM@pkg@draft 
{\AM@pkg@draftfalse
\includepdf[pages=1-2]{example-image-duck}}
\else
\includepdf[pages=-]{example-image-duck}
\fi` perhaps.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh well the OP asked for draft simpler then to do a new if `\newif\ifpdfpreview ..... `\ifpdfpreview  \includepdfpdf[pages=1-2]{abc.pdf}\else\includepdf{abc.pdf}\fi`  and put `\pdfpreviewtrue` in the preamble

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen.  That's the hint I needed.  I used your code inside my own \attach macro that used @UlrikeFischer's \if..\fi construct.  \attach just adds a final argument to \includepdf of pages={1}.  I can't go more than 1 because some attachments have only one page, but that does it for me.  I greatly appreciate your taking the time to answer.

Comment: I'm a women, not a gentlemen.

Comment: Good to know.  My apologies.